# Rejected edit approved after fixing typos

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I noticed that someone suggested an edit to my question which was rightfully rejected by 3 reviewers (https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5211431)

Then someone else corrected some typos in this rejected edit (https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18511321/5) resulting in this edit being approved?

Why is a suggested edit, which has been rejected by 3 reviewers, applied after a different reviewer corrects typo's in it?

Background:
This was confusing to me since [I noticed](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18511321/revisions) that my question was edited with the explanation 'typos' but in fact 158 characters of new content were added to it. I didn't agree with the edit and rolled it back.
Today, I discovered [the 4 recorded reviews](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5211431) for this edit and it didn't seem logical to me that something still gets applied after it has been rejected by 3 different people...
In order to better understand, I figured I would ask here (and thanks to Martijn I now do). My apologies if this wasn't the right question to ask / place to ask it.

Comment: You, as the original author [rolled back all the changes](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18511321/revisions) that were made by these edits. So what is the issue? What is the discussion about?

Comment: I'm just trying to understand why this happened and thought it might have been a bug.

Comment: Ok, the reason is what Martijn said, during peer review, 2 out of 3 people rejected, 1 edited and kept the change

Answer (score 4, accepted):

dabhaid was a reviewer on that suggested edit, and choose to *Improve* option, but then unchecked the *Suggested edit was helpful* box.

As such they both rejected the suggested edit (no points for the suggestor), but *also* still applied the edit, with typos corrected.

Had the reviewer left the checkbox enabled instead, the suggested edit would have been marked as approved.

dabhaid must have started editing when there were (at most) 2 rejections on that suggested edit; it was while editing that the 3rd rejection came in. That's why there are 4 reviews recorded on that suggested edit.